# jQuery - appending array of elements to a class and having it show up on the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Currently, I'm trying to append this new div class of playerhand and then trying to append an array - playerHand - that I've defined somewhere else in my code. It is an array that contains suits/values (playing cards) and I'm trying to have that show up on the DOM.

Right now, the div is showing up on the DOM when I click the deal button but nothing shows up on the div. I've tried text(), append(), add(), and val(), but so far nothing.

When I use the text() method, it returns an array of objects.

```
let suits = ["♦", "♣", "♥", "♠"],
values = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"],
deckOfCards = [],
suit,
value,
points = { A: 11, J: 10, Q: 10, K: 10 },
playerHand = [],
dealerHand = [];


for (const suit of suits) {
 for (const value of values) {

  deckOfCards.push({suit, value, points: points[value] || value});
 }
}

const dealRandomCard = () => {
 return deckOfCards.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
  deckOfCards.length), 1)[0];
}

// console.log(dealRandomCard());


for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  playerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
  dealerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
}


 $(() => {

  $('.deal').on('click', () => {
   $('.gamebox').append('<div class = playerhand > </div>')
   $('.playerhand').append(playerHand)

  // $('.playerhand').text(playerHand)
  // $('.playerhand').val(playerHand)
  // $('.playerhand').add(playerHand)

  })
});
```

Comment: As I can see the array is appending to the div, can you update the question with executable code snippet?

Comment: not sure how to add this code snippet to show that it's just an empty div that has nothing on it. Basically looks like a card with nothing on it

Comment: here's an image of what it looks like when i click the deal button

Comment: Image does not help.....you can only add the relevant part of html like the element with class like `deal` and `gamebox` with the array `playerHand`......

Comment: "*I've tried `text()`, `append()`, `add()`, and `val()`"* - how have you tried these things?

Comment: ah so if i have just an array, I can't append, add, or jQuery just any array to a div?

Comment: It depends what's in the array, and how you work with it; please: show your [mcve] code.

Comment: Could you add an example for playerHand please :)

Comment: EDITED with code that shows my playerHand and what i've done with it

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

You were expecting to append an array of objects to the DOM. Making a div and appending objects to it will not coerce them into strings. You have to deal with extracting the data from these objects then append them as strings to the DOM. Instead of dealing in that headache, just generate the tags at the point in which the card objects are being pushed into the deck.

---

Don't know the nature of your array so that might be your problem. This demo is using an array of strings, more specifically an Array of [HTML entities](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/playing%20card). The surrounding `$(() => {...});` is a mystery so I removed it. Other than the array and the previously mentioned code enigma your code is unchanged.

### Demo

```js
let suits = ["♦", "♣", "♥", "♠"],
  values = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"],
  deckOfCards = [],
  points = {
    A: 11,
    J: 10,
    Q: 10,
    K: 10
  },
  playerHand = [],
  dealerHand = [];


for (const suit of suits) {
  for (const value of values) {
    const score = points[value] || value;
    const card = `<figure class="card" data-points="${score}">
             <figcaption class="face">${suit}</figcaption>
             ${value}</figure>`;
    deckOfCards.push(card);
  }
}

const dealRandomCard = () => {
  return deckOfCards.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() *
    deckOfCards.length), 1)[0];
};

// console.log(dealRandomCard());


function deal(whom) {
  const node = whom === 'player' ? $('.playerHand') : $('.dealerHand');
  const hand = whom === 'player' ? playerHand : dealerHand;
  hand.push(dealRandomCard());
  node.html(hand);
}

$('.deal').on('click', () => {
  deal('player');
  deal('dealer');
});
```

```css
.gamebox {
  display: table;
  min-width: 54px;
}

.deal {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 70%;
}

.playerHand,
.dealerHand {
  display: table-row
}

.card {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 54px;
  line-height: 1.2
}

.face {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='gamebox'>
  <div class='dealerHand'></div>
  <div class='playerHand'></div>
</div>
<button class='deal'>Deal</button>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just append an array to a div, try it with this (not pretty, i know):

```js
$('.deal').on("click", function() {
  var playerHand = ["King Ace", "King Heart"];  // and so on
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  //A string containing a series of divs and the contents of the Array.
  container.innerHTML = '<div>' + playerHand.join('</div><div>') + '</div>';
  //append inner divs to outer div
  $('.gamebox').append(container);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="deal">click Me</button>
  <div class="gamebox"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when i add that within my deal button, it says that appendChild is not a function

Comment: i see what you're trying to do but now it's just showing me an array of objects on the dom. [object Object] [object Object]

Comment: All you have to do now is to style the div's like you want them to look

Comment: Your array contains jsObjects, you try to access their string, so the get a parseError, access them like this: array[i].data, not array[i]

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery class selector returns an array of objects, even if there is only one.
Maybe you want to try :

```
$('.playerhand:first').append(playerHand);
//OR
$('.playerhand').first().append(playerHand);
```

Or concatenate both appends :

```
$('.gamebox').append('<div class="playerHand">' + playerHand + '</div>');
```

This second solution works perfectly fine for me : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n9qvzj4/).

Also, don't forget to add a semicolon at the end of each line : it will make the code easier to read (and faster ?) when you'll build large scripts.